# Rails production 500 error page showing in dev?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason after i re-base my branch with develop, since then i am not getting error page in rails s (development environment) instead i am getting 500 internal server error

What i need to change in order to get it normal?

I see nothing changed in development, production and environment rb files, since that re-base. Below is environment ruby file

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

I found [this](http://www.jagregory.com/writings/rails-500-error-showing-in-dev/) link but could not resolve my issue.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you had some kind of rescue page and right now it's not working and you see just average 500 error?

Comment: Normally when you are in development mode, and if you got some error then that error message is displayed on page, but i am getting 500 internal server error(As we all know that when we are on production only then we get 500 internal server error page)

Comment: this is what i am getting right now http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/docs/images/iis_500_error.png

Comment: Try to find something related to rescue in your controllers. I think you have some kind of global rescue, that handles any expcetion

Comment: Do you see any factical 500 error in your logs?

Comment: Yes i can see error on console, but it did not show on page

Comment: can you post the exact error you saw in your logs?

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    53:         </tr>
    54:         </thead>
    55:         <tbody>
    56:         <% @section.each do |section| %>
    57:             <tr>
    58:               <td><%= section.name %></td>
    59:               <td><%= section.user.full_name %></td>
  
app/views/sections/index.html.erb:56:in `_app_views_sections_index_html_erb___181906619_57475104'

Comment: This is what i get on console:
NoMethodError: undefined method `original_exception' for #<ActionView::Template:
:Error:0x4f2da70>

Comment: It's probably a Gem dependency you have that relies on `original_exception`. This method was removed in Rails 5. The only Gem I can think of that used this was `better_errors`, but it really could be any. The full "framework" stack trace should give you a hint of which Gem dependency it's failing on. Probably also wouldn't hurt to search for instances of `original_exception` in your project.